# Formatting numbers in compose TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, number-formatting, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to create a reusable NumberField component:

```
@Composable
fun NumberField(
  value: Number?,
  onNumberChange: (Number) -> Unit,
) {
  TextField(
    value = value?.toString() ?: "",
    onValueChange = {
      it.toDoubleOrNull()?.let { value ->
        if (value % 1.0 == 0.0) {
          onNumberChange(value.toInt())
        } else {
          onNumberChange(value)
        }
      }
    },
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
  )
}
```

To be used as:

```
@Composable
fun NumberContent() {
  val number = remember { mutableStateOf<Number?>(null) }

  NumberField(value = number.value) {
    number.value = it
  }
}
```

I would like the number to be an Int or Double depending on what the user is typing.  What I have above works until you try to enter a decimal number, as it seems "5.", does not parse as double.  I want to allow the user to type 5. and then fill in rest.  As such I don't want to add a zero after decimal automatically because that might not be the next number they want to enter.  Is this the best way to go about it?  I know that I can just accept any text and then try to format the text they entered later as an int or double and make them fix it then, just thought it would be nice to bundle it all in the composable.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to display when the user type: `5.` ?

Comment: I would like to display 5.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand what you are trying to achieve (if the user types `5.` the default field just displays `5.`). In any case don't use `onValueChange`, but use the `visualTrasformation`

Comment: I would like to limit to only numbers. If the user types 5.Urdu that’s invalid, they should not be able to type that. Or 5.74.64.62 or &@. I would like to restrict the field to only numbers, ints and doubles.

Answer (score 21):

You can use something like:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.isEmpty()){
            text = it
        } else {
            text = when (it.toDoubleOrNull()) {
                null -> text //old value
                else -> it   //new value
            }
        }
    },
    singleLine = true,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!. Just add to it.trim() in new value to avoid whitespaces

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that handles all stated conditions while also exposing the state to parents.

```
@Composable
fun NumberField(
    value: Number?,
    onNumberChange: (Number?) -> Unit,
) {
    val number = remember { mutableStateOf(value) }
    val textValue = remember(value != number.value) {
        number.value = value
        mutableStateOf(value?.toDouble()?.let {
            if (it % 1.0 == 0.0) {
                it.toInt().toString()
            } else {
                it.toString()
            }
        } ?: "")
    }

    val numberRegex = remember { "[-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]*".toRegex() }
    // for no negative numbers use "[\d]*[.]?[\d]*"

    TextField(
        value = textValue.value,
        onValueChange = {
            if (numberRegex.matches(it)) {
                textValue.value = it
                number.value = it.toDoubleOrNull()
                onNumberChange(number.value)
            }
        },
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
    )
}
```

An example usage is shown below.

```
@Composable
fun DemoUsage() {
    Column {
        val number = remember { mutableStateOf<Number?>(null) }
        
        NumberField(value = number.value) {
            number.value = it
        }

        Button(onClick = { number.value = number.value?.toDouble()?.plus(1) }) {
            Text("Increment")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works good. The one problem is that when the value is 0 and you backspace it doesn't erase the 0. If you backspace the 0 and type 1 you end up with 10.

Comment: You need to remove remove `value != number.value` from the second remember so it updates when doing things like removing trailing zeros. Then add `if (it == 0.0) { "" }` at the top of the if else chain in the second remember so you can erase 0 values.